# Downloading .gradle folder

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Can anyone tell me how to download .gradle folder and all of its components in android studio?

I want to download it manually because I don't have any internet connection in my PC.

Comment: This folder is mainly used as a cache by gradle. It's content depends on your specific build. Therefore it is unique and cannot be downloaded from somewhere.

Comment: So I strictly need a connection on PC to download it??

Comment: Yes. Once you have downloaded all needed dependencies you can use gradle's offline mode. You need then only again an online connection when some dependencies change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And a small question:when does the dependencies change?

Comment: The dependencies change if you change it in the build.gradle file.